# Rvest: Scraping multiple URLs from csv

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape a certain element from multiple websites. One by one rvest works fine, but is there a possibility to scrape all URL at once? I have a csv file with all the URL, but I can't insert more than a single string value in read_html. Do you have an idea? Thx in advance

Right now I work like this:

```
 test1<- read_html("https://www.startnext.com/higchic")

Site1 <- test1 %>% 
  html_nodes(".js-accordeon:nth-child(4) .accordeon__answer") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.character()

test2<- read_html("https://www.startnext.com/sauberkasten")

Site2 <- test2 %>% 
  html_nodes(".js-accordeon:nth-child(4) .accordeon__answer") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.character()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape a few at a time by concatenating the URLs, but more than a few will lead to errors. Please let me know if you find out how.

Here's the code:

```
 url <- c("https://www.vox.com/", "https://www.bbc.com/")
 page <-map(url, ~read_html(.x) %>% html_nodes("p") %>% html_text())
 str(page)
```